# Assign the vaule of property of the user control get error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have website which has usercontrol, I can load the control. However if I assign the value of property of the user control, I get error" Type "WebUserControl) is not defined. Can someone told me how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

There is the code to use my Usercontrol

```
Partial Class Test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles form1.Load

    Dim ctrl As Control
    ctrl = Page.LoadControl("Management/Profile/WebUserControl.ascx")
    ctrl.ID = "ctrl_1"
    CType(ctrl, WebUserControl).Level = 6 //this line cause error
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl)

  End Sub

End Class
```

Here is my WebUserControl

```
Partial Class  Management_Profile_WebUserControl
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
Private m_Level As Integer

Public Property Level() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_Level
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        m_Level = Value
    End Set
End Property



Protected Sub Management_Profile_WebUserControl_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TextBox1.Text = m_Level
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: see the following link and also make sure your path is correct
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: @PEO the path is corrected. If I didn't assign the property value of usercontrol, I can see the textbox and label of the user control. I followed the link and create the same usercontrol. However I still got the Type'MyControl is not defined'

Comment: my project is website, not web app. Does it cause the problem?